# com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosSQLException: Failed to grow the connection pool

Tags: java, database, database-connection, sqlexception, atomikos

I'm using Apache tomcat 8.5, I have configured below data source in context.xml file in Tomcat

I'm getting com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosSQLException: Failed to grow the connection pool. What is the issue in above configuration

Comment: I have fixed the issue by reordering the element. The jdbc name should not come first positio, it should come third or fourth position

Comment: did you get this error while using atomikos api in JTA transaction with spring?

I am getting the same error while using atomikos and when i start my application. how did you resolve this issue?

Comment: we can fix the issue by reordering the elements like jdbc name should come third or fourth position